# Pyramid directory structure confusion

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a pyramid project with the following directory structure. Inside my views.py, I have this line of code that specifies where my template is.

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemp.pt')
```

Now, I get an error since it is looking for my template inside my view directory. Even if I give the path as "demo/templates/mytemp.pt" I get the same error.

```
ValueError: Missing template asset: demo.view:templates/mytemp.pt (/home/Demo/demo/view/templates/mytemp.pt)
```

This is my directory structure:-

```
   Demo/
    |-- Demo.egg-info
    `-- demo
        |-- errors
        |-- model
        |-- scripts
        |-- static
        |   `-- somefolder
        |-- templates
        |-- test
        `-- view
```

My views.py is inside the view folder and mytem.pt sits inside templates folder.Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you just append `../` to the beginning of the `renderer` argument?

Comment: @samGbos: ValueError: Missing template asset: demo.view:../template/mytemp.pt (/home/Demo/demo/view/../template/mytemp.pt)

Comment: detect typo (template->templateS), try `../templates/mytemp.pt`

Comment: uralbash and @samGbos, you make my day. Thank you :)Can you please add this as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending `../` to the beginning of the renderer argument seems to work.
:)

Answer (score 4):

Try the [asset specification](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/glossary.html#term-asset-specification):

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='demo:templates/mytemp.pt')
```

or possibly with a capital "D" in "Demo" if that's how your project is named:

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='Demo:templates/mytemp.pt')
```

Comment: It says ImportError: No module named Demo

Comment: Is that not the name of your project? Try `demo:` then, with a lowercase 'd'

Comment: @Tania, the asset specification is probably preferred to `../` since it makes the root your project directory and works up from there. It also provides some safety so that you don't mistakenly look outside your project directory. In Pyramid, the asset specification (which just means using `demo:`) is useful almost anywhere you need to point to a file/directory within your directory structure, as it provides a logical starting point for your directory path.

Comment: -- and you don't have to think about where your current file is (the one you're writing in) in relation to the file you want to point at - especially useful if you later decide to move files around and into other directories.

Comment: You can add this as an answer @Raj since it gives some really useful information.. ++1 for your explanation.